# How to pass a .txt file to a function in Python?

Tags: python, string, function, file, tuples

I am asked to create a function which takes a string argument, creates and returns a tuple containing details about a person specified by the string (for example, first name, second name, and salary). The string is with a layout: first name, second name, salary. Then I have to create another function that takes the tuple as an argument and prints the details about the person in fixed-width fields on a single line with this layout: salary, first name, second name. It is important to mention that the strings must be taken from a file input that the user gives. This is what I tried:

```
file = input('Insert a file:')

try:
    fin = open(file)
except IOError as a:
    fin = None
    print('Failed to open', file)

def person(fin):
    my_str = open('fin', 'r').read()
    print(tuple(my_str))
```

Help of any kind would be appreciated because I am completely lost. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you looking to pass the name of a file to a program? or to a function?

Comment: The `open('fin', 'r')` part doesn't make sense as you probably have no file named 'fin' but an already opened file object in variable fin.

Comment: @fiacre well I have to open the file within the program and then pass is to a function #1 which takes the content as a string and then turn it into a tuple. Then function #2 must output the content of the tuple in fixed-width fields on a single line.

Comment: @MichaelButscher yes you are correct. I tried with open(fin, 'r') but it threw me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's convert this task in many little and easier to solve tasks.

### First function

```
def string_to_tuple(person_string):
    """ Converts a string into a tuple.
    person_string must be in the following format: "first_name last_name salary"
    A tuple of the following format is returned: (first_name, last_name, salary)
    salary must be an int. If it can be a float change int to float

    e.g.
    >>> string_to_tuple("John Miller 100")
    ('John', 'Miller', 100)
    """
    first_name, last_name, salary = person_string.split(" ")
    return first_name, last_name, int(salary)
```

This function takes a string splits it at whitespace and returns a tuple. Note that no error checking was done. You should, later on, check if the input is valid.

### Second function

```
def tuple_to_string(person_tuple):
    """Converts a tuple with person data into a string. This is is inverse function to `string_to_tuple`.

    person_tuple must be in the following format: (first_name, last_name, salary)
    A string of the following format is returned: "first_name last_name salary"

    e.g.
    >>> string_person = "John Miller 100"
    >>> string_person_2 = tuple_to_string(string_to_tuple(string_person))
    >>> string_person == string_person_2
    True
    >>> tuple_to_string(('John', 'Miller', 100))
    'John Miller 100'
    """
    string_person = " ".join(str(i) for i in person_tuple)
    return string_person
```

Here you join a tuple back into a string. Before you can join you need to convert every item into a string (`str(i)`).

### Reading from a file

For reading, you should use the [with](https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm). This ensures, that the file is **always** closed when it is not used anymore.

#### Opening a file:

```
path_to_file = "my_file.txt"
with open(path_to_file, "r") as file:
    content = file.read() # alternatives: file.readlines() or file.readline()

print(content) # To ensure the content was correctly read. Not needed in the later application
```

The path of the file must be either relative to your current working directory (Where your script is) or absolute.

#### Difference between file and path

There is a difference between a path of a file (`path_to_file`) and an actually opened file (`file`). The path can be entered by the user and you have to use it to open the file. The user cannot enter a file object.

```
>>> type(path_to_file)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(file)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
```

A possible comparison that is easier to understand may be the following: Think of a public library: The library has books and every book has a title. If you want to read a book, you need to find this book by title, get an exemplar open it and read it. In this example, a **book title** is a **filename** and a **book** is a **file**.

### Read from file and call function

Now the last step is to put all things together. So first read from the file and then call the previously created functions. The read depends on your file structure. I just assume you have in each line data for a new person.

```
with open(path_to_file, "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        tuple_person = string_to_tuple(line)
        print(tuple_person) # verify output
```

If you have any questions to a part your welcome to ask it in the comments.

### Edit

### Adjustments based on file content

One line in the file is as follows: Chelsea Right-back Davide Zappacosta 20,000,000

You need to expand the tuples:

original: `first_name, last_name, salary`

new: `team, position, first_name, last_name, salary`

Note: For now just keep the salary as s string and not convert it to an int or float.

original: `return first_name, last_name, int(salary)`

new: `return team, position, first_name, last_name, salary`

and

original: `string_person = " ".join(str(i) for i in person_tuple)`

new: `string_person = " ".join(person_tuple)`

### Resources

- [reading-and-writing-files](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)
- [split method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)
- [join method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)
- [too-many-values-to-unpack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/) Should be a hint how to solve your error. If this doesn't help, post the content of the file you want to read in.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The program gives output but it returns an error as well: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abc/Desktop/test.py", line 39, in <module>
    tuple_person = string_to_tuple(line)
  File "C:/Users/abc/Desktop/test.py", line 11, in string_to_tuple
    first_name, last_name, salary = person_string.split(" ")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: Ok, I saw the change you made and it makes sense. However, I don't really understand the code part...

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev I think I know the problem, but to verify it, can you add the content of your file to your question? The problem is, that this function assumes, that you enter a string in exactly the format i.e. 3 words seperated by spaces.

Comment: Which of the code parts do you not understand? I can try to simplify them or explain them better

Comment: The "Difference between file and path". Everything else seems clear. Should I insert this code?

Comment: The content of the file is about players. For example: Chelsea Right-back Davide Zappacosta 20,000,000

Comment: Thank you for your time. Is it ok to drop a comment if I have any further questions about the task since this is not the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

just of the top of my head, fin is a variable but you pass it as a plain text string

```
    my_str = open(fin, 'r').read()
```

Comment: Even if I try to do it this way it gives me an error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Comment: fin is the file buffer that is already opened for reading.  Do not open it again -- makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import argparse

def my_func(my_file): 
    with open(my_file_name, 'r') as f_obj:
        # do stuff with f_obj, like f_obj.read()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--infile', type=str, help='Name of file to read', required=True)
options = parser.parse_args()
input_file_name = options.infile

my_func(input_file_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to write `fin = open(file, "wt")` in your `try` statement. The `wt` at the end means that you **write** using **text** (you can also write in binary)

Later on you need to put `my_str = open(fin, 'r')` since `fin` is a object and not the name of the actual file

Comment: He is reading a file -- not writing.  "wt" is not needed "w" is sufficient.  fin is a file object -- not a variable.